# How can I have a custom 404 page using Middleman?

Tags: middleman

I have followed all documentation guides, so I have the following line in my `config.rb`

```
page '/404.html', directory_index: false
```

Also, I have a `source/404.html.erb` page. I'm not sure what I'm I doing wrong, I am only able to see the `File not found` error page generated by default.
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I managed to solve the problem, what I did was:

In my **Config.rb**

- I left this at global level **`page '/404.html'**, layout: 'error'`
- Removed this **`activate :relative_assets`**
- In `production` and `staging` blocks I modified  error document to **`s3_sync.error_document = '404/index.html'`**, this was the cause why I was losing my assets as once the site has been deployed `404.html` does not exist anymore, I was pointing to the wrong `error_document`

I created a separate layout called `error` as suggested on this thread for my `404` page.

I am using

- 'middleman', '~> 4.1', '>= 4.1.10'
- 'middleman-s3_sync', '~> 4.0', '>= 4.0.2'
- "webpack": "~3.5.5"

Hope this help somebody else in the same issue.

Check this [Middleman blog](https://forum.middlemanapp.com/t/custom-error-page-404/981/12?u=willibaur) if you want to see the whole thread.

Comment: Thanks for the follow up solution! Do you have any clue how a dev might pull this off with github pages?